# Clusters in residuals v fitted diagnostic plot

Tags: regression, diagnostic

I'm fitting a linear model in R with a (non-transformed) response variable and two independent variables: one of them is continuous and the other is numeric but treated as an ordinal variable with four discrete levels. When I run my diagnostic plot it get these:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(fullmodel_revised)
```

[image]

```
plot(density(fullmodel_revised[['residuals']]))
hist(dataset$depvariable)
```

[image]
[image]

I understand that my Q-Q plot suggests my distribution has rather light tails. However I'm confused about the clustering in my residuals v fitted plot - I suspect it's because one of my covariates is an ordinal variable with four bins, but is being treated like a continuous variable. Otherwise the dots don't exhibit any patterns. Wondering if this is problematic in terms of fitting a model, and its predictive power? Any advice welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

At a guess only the 4 levels predictor is of much use in your model.
The other continuous predictor doesn't add much.

A display of `lm` results would show more.

If so, then to a good first (zeroth?) approximation your fitted values are 4 distinct values corresponding to the means for each level of that ordinal predictor.

A scatter plot matrix would add to your helpful displays of residual plots, even though one variable is discrete. You need to look once again at the original data to find out more surely what is going on.